# removing multiple items from list of list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I need to remove items from a list in the following manner:
given two numbers:

```
num1 = 2
num2 = 5
#These are arbitraty (can be different than 2 or 5)
```

and the list:

```
[[10, 10], [20, 20], [30, 30], [40, 40], [50, 50], [60, 60], [70, 70], [80, 80], [90, 90], [100, 100]]
```

I need to remove all items that are in between these two nums, such that the following output will be created:

```
[[10, 10], [20, 20], [60, 60], [70, 70]]
```

so the 1st and 2nd numbers are kept, the 3rd, 4th, and 5th are removed, the 6th and 7th are kept, and the rest is removed

I've tried to create a certain loop that deletes items, but couldn't quite figure how to run over indexes.

thx for the help!

Comment: Please show what your attempt was. As it stands, this is too broad; your requirement seems completely arbitrary

Comment: you wanted to remove between 2 and 5, so why elements beyond 7th are removed? please clarify

Comment: There are plenty of prior questions here that demonstrate removing items from a list, or building a new list from slices of an old one.  Please show the failing code and how the prior answers don't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep the first 2 out of 5 for every 5 items:

```
data = [[10, 10], [20, 20], [30, 30], [40, 40], [50, 50], [60, 60], [70, 70],
        [80, 80], [90, 90], [100, 100]]

num1 = 2
num2 = 5  # num2 must be > num1

new_data = [x for i,x in enumerate(data) if i%num2 < num1 ]


print(new_data)
```

Output:

```
[[10, 10], [20, 20], [60, 60], [70, 70]]
```

The trick is to use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and modulo the given index of your original data by `num2` - you keep those that are less then `num1`.

```
index :   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, ...
i%num2:   0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4, ...
keep:     x x - - - x x - - -  ...
```

Comment: `in (0,1)` actually just means less than 2. The solution could be made better by replacing `if i%num2 in (0,1)` by `if i%num2 < num1`. Right now, this solution doesn't update if you change `num1`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Just letting you know, assuming this is a typo, it says `if i%num2 in < num1` right now.

Comment: @python_beginner  0 and 1 are below 2 - this worked(ish) for num1=2 - fixed it with input from tommy - it's better to use like he suggested

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I'm assuming you mean this:

1. Delete elements from `num1` to `num2`
2. Delete elements after `num1 + num2`

Just use the `del` operator and list slicing:

```
>>> mylist = [[10, 10], [20, 20], [30, 30], [40, 40], [50, 50], [60, 60], [70, 70], [80, 80], [90, 90], [100, 100]]
>>> num1, num2 = 2, 5
>>> mylist = mylist[:num1 + num2]
>>> mylist
[[10, 10], [20, 20], [30, 30], [40, 40], [50, 50], [60, 60], [70, 70]]
>>> del mylist[num1:num2]
>>> mylist
[[10, 10], [20, 20], [60, 60], [70, 70]]
```

Please clarify if you mean something different.

Comment: Hey! I actually ment to keep 2 files out of 5, for every 5 items @Tomothy32